# Java URL constructor error

Tags: java, url, constructor

When I try to instantiate an object from the URL class like this:

```
URL myURL = new URL("http://example.com");
```

the compiler arise and error:

> error: constructor URL in class URL cannot be applied to given types;

and points to the key work 'new' in the line above. The all class is:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URL {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    URL myURL = new URL("http://example.com");

    String protocl = myURL.getProtocol();

    System.out.println(protocol);
  }
}
```

plz help !!

Comment: It's a conflict between the name of your class, and the `java.net.URL` class that you imported. Don't name your class `URL`.

Answer (score 5):

Your class name is `URL` but you are probably trying to instantiate a new `java.net.URL` object.  Since you didn't specifically say which URL object you were creating the compiler assumed it was your object and it doesn't have a constructor that takes a `String`.  Rename your class to something else and the problem should go away.